# Using Django partially

Tags: python, django, redis

Is it possible to use only some features of Django?

I'm using my own home-made ORM with redis for a webapp using the MVC model. Now I want to know what I have to do to so that I can take advantage of Django's very nice admin.py

Has anyone ever done anything similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "use only some features of Django", but some parts depend on other parts. Django Admin is very dependent on Django ORM. It is basically a tool for visualizing, creating and editing Django ORM models. Using it with your own "home-made" ORM is virtually impossible.

Take a look at [django-nonrel](http://django-nonrel.org/). It forks Django to provide support for non-relational databases (currently MongoDB and Google App Engine). It might help you if your main aim is to use a non-sql db in your project. It still won't help you to easily integrate your custom ORM with Django Admin. So your other option is to write your own admin for your project.

Comment: Damn it. Avoiding writing my own admin was exactly what I wanted.